# Canvas function

Tags: javascript, html

I have to do a program with JavaScript that every two seconds increases the number until 10. I have done one that increases the number by pressing a key, but I don't know how to do the other. This is the code that I already have:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title>COUNTING</title>
<style>
#canvas{
 border-style:solid;
 background-color: #f17256;
// background-image: url("");
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="300"><b>This browser does not support canvas.</b></canvas>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var times = 0
var text = {
 font: "60px OPTIMA",
 color:"black",
 x: Math.random()*canvas.width,
 y: Math.random()*canvas.height,
 draw: function (){
 ctx.font=this.font;
 ctx.fillStyle= this.color;
 ctx.fillText(times, this.x, this.y);
 }
};
function drawCanvas() {
 ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 text.draw();
}

document.addEventListener("load", drawCanvas());
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(){
 text.x=Math.random()*canvas.width;
 text.y=Math.random()*canvas.height;

 if (times<10) times++;
 else times = "GAME OVER";
 drawCanvas();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use this full code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title>COUNTING</title>
<style>
#canvas{
    border-style:solid;
    background-color:   #f17256;
//  background-image: url("");
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="300"><b>This browser does not support canvas.</b></canvas>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var times = 0
var text = {
    font: "60px OPTIMA",
    color:"black",
    x: Math.random()*canvas.width,
    y: Math.random()*canvas.height,
    draw: function (){
    ctx.font=this.font;
    ctx.fillStyle= this.color;
    ctx.fillText(times, this.x, this.y);
    }
};

function drawCanvas() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    text.draw();
}

function addNumber() {
    times++;
}

setInterval(addNumber, 2000);

document.addEventListener("load", drawCanvas());
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(){
    text.x=Math.random()*canvas.width;
    text.y=Math.random()*canvas.height;

    if (times<10) times++;
    else times = "GAME OVER";
    drawCanvas();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Added `setInterval()` command and `addNumber` function

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the keyDown listener, you can use a setInterval() to do it.

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    text.x=Math.random()*canvas.width;
    text.y=Math.random()*canvas.height;

    if (times<10) {
        times++;
    } else {
        times = "GAME OVER";
        clearInterval(interval)
    }
    drawCanvas();
}, 2000);
```